# Is there a way in bamboo to execute bamboo build periodically at certain time but ONLY if there are repository changes?

Tags: bamboo

I've a bamboo plan setup but I want to run my job everyday at 9 in the night but the build has to run only if there are any changes in the git. How can I do that combination thing in bamboo? I can see only fewer options in the triggering section like the repository changes, Cron job, Single daily build, trigger base on the outcome of other plans. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't answer that because it's been a while since I last used bamboo but last time I was in charge of one of those, I had a build to run every hour (?!?) and it only build if the revision was different. I think there is an option somewhere to check.

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to "Triggers" tab in your Build Plan configuration.
2. Add trigger "Repository polling"
3. Edit the Schedule to "Daily", "Once per day"
   and select desired time.

The build will be created only if you have some changes in repository.